# What are the typical ways to solve "invalid string offset" errors from ld?

Tags: linux, makefile, ld, qmake

I am building a project and I am getting an error along the lines of

```
...//this_lib.so: error adding symbols: File format not recognised
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

above this this line is displayed

`...//this_lib.so: invalid string offset 1437763608 >= 38801 for section '.dynstr'`

I am trying to fix this issue. `this_lib.so` is a lib that is built in the make process (so build by me).

How do I debug issues like these?

At first I thought that it could be a 32-bit lib, that is not the case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, if you add more tags (your programming language etc.) you can find your answer more quickly.

Comment: Write down the commands that `make` executes when you run make on a clean build. Execute these command yourself step-by-step. After each command check if there is an error and verify that the result is what you expect. Eventually you will find the step that fails or does something wrong. If you cannot figure out what goes wrong, update your question with the all commands you executed and any output/error messages.